# How to solve this estimate in Grafakos' book?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

Prove that for all $1<p<\infty $ there exist a constant $A_p>0$ such that for every $C^2_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$(twice continuously differentiable with compact support complex value function) such that
$$||\partial{x_1}f||_{L^p}+||\partial{x_2}f||_{L^p}\leq A_p||\partial{x_1}f+i\partial{x_2}f||_{L^p}$$
Well,This problem is one of the exercise in Grafakos' GTM 249  Singular Integral Chapter(Sec 5.2 Page 354)[See](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Ebishop/classes/math638.F20/Grafakos_Classical_Fourier_Analysis.pdf).
It seems much easier than any other problem in this chapter,But I have no idea of it,Even after  finishing the other exercise in this section,May anyone give me some hint or correct solution?Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @Oliver Díaz Thanks your comment first .It's my fault to omit the condition that $f$ is complex value function.I'm going to correct that.

Comment: What do you mean by $L^p$ norm ? Two dimensional ?

Comment: If $f$ is holomorphic in the  large part $U$ of  its support then the integrand  on the right hand side vanishes on $U.$ Therefore I doubt if the inequality holds for complex valued functions.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc Thanks for your comment.Yes its two dimensional situation.But such analytic function must be zero function，so the inequality still holds.

Comment: I mentioned analytic only on part of its support.  So such functions exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} = -R_j(R_1-i R_2)\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} + i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\Big)$, for $j=1,2$, where $R_j$ is the $j$-th Riesz transform.

Comment: Thank you!!!I have finished this exercise with this delicate equality!

Comment: Your welcome. Your posting reminded me of the Riesz transform. I took a look at my old notes in Harmonic Analysis and realize that was a problem (which I did solve back when) in my notes.